# inconsistent endianess in binary file

Tags: c, binaryfiles, endianness

I wrote a program to write numbers into binary file, a snippet is as below:

```
    u_int16_t N=150;
    u_int16_t seed=3;

    FILE * outfile, *infile;

    outfile=fopen("tempfile","wb");
    //write these 2 16-bit numbers into binary file
    fwrite(&seed, 2, 1, outfile);
    fwrite(&N, 2, 1, outfile);

    infile=fopen("tempfile","rb");
    if(infile==NULL) fputs("Fire error\n",stderr);
    //get the size of the file
    fseek(infile,0,SEEK_END);
    int lsize=ftell(infile);
    rewind(infile);

    u_char * temp2=(u_char*)malloc(lsize);
    if(temp2==NULL) printf("temp2 error allocation\n");
    fread(temp2,1,lsize,infile);
    for(i=0;i<lsize;i++)
    printf("%x",temp2[i]);
    printf("\n");
    fclose(infile);
    free(temp2);
```

the results are:

```
30960
```

so 3 is printed as `30`, which is little endian
while 150 is printed as `960`, there is an aditional `0`, and actually `0x96=150` , so it is big endian

why the endianess is different for `3` and `150`, and why there is an additional `0` ?
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
printf("%x",temp2[i]);
```

Bytes that have a leading zero in their hexadecimal number is printed *without* that zero. This means that a number such as, for example, `0x03` will be printed as `3`.

This is quite obvious by you writing four bytes to the file, but only have five hexadecimal digits in the printed output (hint: four bytes are eight hexadecimal digits).

Instead do e.g.

```
printf("%02x",temp2[i]);
```

Comment: ah, thanks, I get `03009600`, so this means my system is little-endian?

Comment: @user138126 Yes I would say so.